# How to set up a schema to use for generating proxy classes

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl, code-generation, webservice-client

I'm consuming a WSDL and in this WSDL there're some methods and types defined.

Here's an example of the XML in the WSDL:

```
<operation name="GETSTUFF">
  <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="GETSTUFF"/>
  <input name="GETSTUFFSRequest">
    <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
  </input>
  <output name="GETSTUFFSResponse">
    <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
  </output>
</operation>
```

The generated method looks like this `client.GETSTUFF()` which is not that pretty. 
The same goes for the complex types defined in the WSDL and the corresponding proxy classes generated when adding a service reference from Visual Studio.

So how do I control how the generated proxy classes and methods are named?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really more of a question for the people who wrote the service. If their operation is named GETSTUFF, then your proxy operation will be named GETSTUFF.

Comment: Yes, I know. But the service is as is and I'm not able to get it changed.

Comment: Then, really, all you can practically do is write wrapper methods with whatever names you like. Either that or, just do nothing.

Answer (score -1):

If you import the WSDL using wsdl.exe, you can use the /parameters command line parameter to pass an XML file with parameters.
That XML file can reference a SchemaImporterExtension class. You can write a SchemaImporterExtension to format the generated code according to your wishes.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.advanced.schemaimporterextension.aspx for the SchemaImporterExtension class you must inherit your implementation from, and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w46ccb0h.aspx for a sample program.

Comment: FYI: this customization capability only applies to XML Web Services (ASMX) **not** WCF proxies.

Comment: If not using the wsdl.exe then what's the better choice?

Comment: To those suggesting svcutil: That tool will not solve the problem.
Using wsdl.exe it is possible - even if that tool is not the preferred one these days.